# How do i create a delete link to a message on my microblog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a small app with a bar to post messages and I want to add a delete button to every message so I can delete it.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.save
      redirect_to "/home/show_msg"
    else
      render :action => "/home/home_page"
    end
  end

  def home_page
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def show_msg
    @postwords = Message.all
  end

  def index
  end
end
```

View (home_page):

```
<center><h1>MiNibloG</h1></center>
<br>
<br>

<div align="center">
<%= form_for @message, :url => "/home/create" do |f| %>
<%= f.label :postword %>
<%= f.text_field :postword %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

View (show_msg):

```
<center>
<h1>Posts list</h1>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
  <% @postwords.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.postword %><br><br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</center>
```

And this is the migration:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :postword

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :messages
  end
end
```

Comment: probably you should post your code in your question, so that anyone can help.

Comment: You need to clean up the code in your question so it's easily readable. Right now it's impossible to make it out.

Comment: yeah, im new to that platform and im trying to figure it out how to arrange this right.

Comment: i fixed it but you kept undoing my changes :) select a block of code and then click the curly braces in the toolbar.

Comment: ohh sorry buddy :) , k now i know thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the scaffolding, scaffold fits ideally for you situation.

```
rails generate scaffold message postwords:string
```

This command generate for you views, controller and migration.

For deleting with your own non REST controller, use something like code below(didnt test it)

```
 <% @postwords.each do |p| %>
        <%= p.postword %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy(p) %><br>
 <% end %>
```

in controller:

```
  def destroy
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to some_route }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

add destroy action in the routes.rb